# Where to filter session expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Here is the problem I have noticed, when users session has expired, and he/she clicks on a link on the web application e.g
http://www.mywebsite.com/myreport.aspx?picture=1
They are taken to the page, instead of a logout or new login page.

I want to write some code somewhere so that before it reaches the Page_Init it checks for some conditions..I thought every request must pass through global.asax but apparently the one I mentioned above, doesn't and directly goes to the page, where it throws all kinds of errors. 
I can write code in each page but that would not be very elegant at all, so therefore I want to write it some place where EVERY request must pass, with or without session..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

> I thought every request must pass through global.asax but apparently the one I mentioned above, doesn't.

You thought right, I would concentrate your efforts on finding out why the events in global.asax don't appear to be firing.

> They are taken to the page, instead of a logout or new login page.

If you are using Forms Authentication, rather than rolling your own, then Session expiry has nothing to do with expiration of the Forms Authentication ticket.  Therefore you shouldn't expect the user to be redirected to a login page.

> goes to the page, where it throws all kinds of errors

You don't say what errors, but presumably you mean null reference exceptions when trying to access objects in Session.  The best practice here is to simply silently recreate the Session objects from persistent storage (e.g. a database) if possible.  But if you can't do that, you should check for null and e.g. redirect to a home page.  You should be able to do this in the `Application_AcquireRequestState` event handler in global.asax, which is the first event in global.asax where Session is available.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have tried the Application_BeginRequest of the global.asax. If that did not work, you can try to create an Http module. Go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zec9k340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the documentation.

Basically Http modules give you facility to hook into the ASP.Net request handling, so that you can add custom logic. There is a detailed walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms227673.aspx) for creating a module.

Answer (score 0):

Create CheckSession method in a helper class and call it from Page_Init in first line in the base page, now all pages where you want to validate session inherit them from that base page.

if session is expired CheckSession can redirect user to a defined page.

if session is expired ASP.NET does not redirect to any page, but code will not find data previously saved in session.

Comment: it just a method call duplicated on the pages where required to check for session validity, session checking logic is not duplicated. This gives better control when not all page access required to login first. Could you please explain where do you see "massive code duplication" here?

Comment: I note you said, "first line on each page". That's a lot of duplication.

Comment: I have improved answer to suggest using base page to avoid code duplication.